# Can I pass a function down as props and have it modify other props in the child component?

Tags: reactjs

Class "App" receives two props - isClicked(bool) & onClick(func)
My intention is to toggle between red/blue text when a div area is clicked.

But this logic is called from another class, called "Call". Call will pass the initial boolean prop (isClicked) and the onClick function down to App.

I don't understand how this onClick() function that is defined in the Call class can modify the App.props.isClicked variable.

What is the best way to approach this problem?
Here is my code in action:
https://codesandbox.io/s/03m408930w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Call was the parent component for App all you need to do is add isClicked as a prop when we call the  component. And we store the value of isClicked in the state of our  component. So everytime it's clicked our state changes which rerenders app.

I edited your code and here it is 
https://codesandbox.io/s/31pl8zp7n1